# What, how to gain from websitespark?

Tags: websitespark

I got OS and software licenses from websiteSpark,

I am asking how "from point of view" to gain the most from websitespark.

for example, they give windows server  2008, but i found it useless, because i asked many hosting companies and they told me that getting hosting with its windows is a must, and they don't allow others to install OS.

Can you share how it will help developers, and small start up individual companies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having Windows Server licenses is only useful if you need dedicated boxes. In which case, hosting providers who participate in the BizSpark/WebsiteSpark program can offer you dedicated boxes for what is essentially the cost of the hardware. This is an even bigger deal with SQL Server, which can get very expensive depending on your configuration.

Or you can host your own boxes. Either way, WebsiteSpark has basically eliminated the licensing costs for a startup using the MS stack. Of course you still have to pay for your hardware, electricity bills, etc - but that doesn't make it useless!

Comment: I think Rex is dead on.  In addition, this program is suited more for the development phase vs the deployment phase of your startup.  They named it "spark" for a reason, because once the flame starts burning, it won't be free to keep it lit.  Take advantage while you can, its a great program.